# python - I need to send more then one socket.send() to only one http request

Tags: python, sockets, http, httpresponse, httpserver

I need to create a basic http-server for my "Computers Network" class. 
In my project the client asks the server (by a GET request) to send a file. 
The server needs to respond with an HTTP response that includes information about the file (e.g. file size, file name) and in addition it should also send the requested file. The file can be from any type (e.g. binary, text). 
From my understanding the client can get only one server's response on every request.So in my case, after receiving the HTTP response with the file data, the 
actual file is not received.
Any ideas?

My server's code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys

root = "J:\\Computers network  - Cyber\\HTTP-Server\\"
serverSocket=socket.socket()
serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))
serverSocket.listen(1)

(clientSocket, clientAddress)=serverSocket.accept()
clientRequest = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print clientRequest

requestSplit = clientRequest.split()

for i in xrange(2):
   if requestSplit[0] == "GET":

      response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" 

      if len(requestSplit[1]) > 1:

         fileRequestList = requestSplit[1].split('/')
         filePath = requestSplit[1].replace('/','\\')
         print "Client asked for " + filePath

         if os.path.isfile(root + filePath):

            try:
               # Writing the response
               fileSize = os.path.getsize(root + filePath) 
               response += "content-Length: " + str(fileSize) + "\r\n"
               print response
               clientSocket.send(response) 


               # Finding and sending the file name and the actual file
               print "File path " + filePath + " exists"
               f = open(root + filePath,'rb')
               fileToSend = f.read()
               print "The file path: " + filePath + "\n"
               clientSocket.send(root+filePath + "\n")
               clientSocket.send(fileToSend)


            except:                
               e = sys.exc_info()[0]
               print "ERROR is ==> " + str(e) + "\n"


         else:
            print "File path " + filePath + " does not exist"



      if i == 1:
         #for loop runs 2 times and only the cliest socket closing.
         clientSocket.close()

   else:
      # If the server did not got GET request the client socket closing.
      clientSocket.close()

   #fileToSend = ""
   #filePath = ""
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: From a high level point of view, you have two ways to do that : either use 2 requests from client (first get metadata, name, size and an id if name is not enough, and second gets actual data) or use one stuctured answer containing both metadata and data (think of XML, json or bson format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metadata that you wish to send can probably be sent in [header response fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields). The file size itself goes in `Content-Length` (which you are already sending in your example code), the file type should be given as a MIME type in `Content-Type`, and a suggested file name can go in `Content-Disposition`.

I should mention that each header line must be terminated by a CR-LF pair, i.e., `\r\n` and the final header line should be followed by a blank line before the actual data. In other words, the last header line should be followed by an extra CR-LF pair.

From Wikipedia [List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields):

> The header fields are transmitted after the request or response line, which is the first line of a message. Header fields are colon-separated name-value pairs in clear-text string format, terminated by a carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) character sequence. The end of the header section is indicated by an empty field, resulting in the transmission of two consecutive CR-LF pairs.

Comment: Hi PM 2Ring, Thank you for you quick reply. In order to actually send the file I use "clientSocket.send(fileToSend)" but if I want to use the response for both the file and the meta-data, then I need one response to contain both. If I understand your answer correctly, the response should be an HTTP response with all the meta-data in its fields. Can I use an HTTP response to include both meta-data and the actual file? Can you show me how? Thank you, Alon

Comment: You can make your program more flexible if it can respond to `HEAD` requests as well as `GET` requests. With a `HEAD` request you respond by just sending all the header data, as if you were responding to a `GET` but without actually appending the file data.; user agents can use `HEAD` requests to decide if the want to fetch a resource before making the `GET` request.

Comment: (Take 2). You should combine all the header info and the file data you are sending into one string and then send that in one go. As I mentioned above, make sure that there's a blank line between the header info & the file data.

Comment: Sorry about that previous comment saying you **must** encode non-text files. That's true of some protocols, but not HTTP. My excuse is that I don't normally work with this stuff at such a low level.  But I did remember the correct info after a few minutes. :) And if you like my answer, please feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. :)